# Read username/password through sockets

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, telnet

I am trying to implement a simple telnet server in python from scratch.
i can read/write data bytes using recv and send methods of my socket object,
but i doesn't know a way to read username and password.
can anybody please help me?

thanks a lot

Comment: Please add to the question the things you've tried and the place you're getting stuck. and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score -2):

If your intention is to read inputs from an end user.You can use Input() function.

```
UserName = input("Enter the user name:")
Password = input("Enter the password for {0}:".format(UserName))
```

You can user variable UserName and Password .

You could better start from [Python.org](http://www.Python.org)